# How to reduce the image size while uploading the image?

Tags: php

While uploading an Image, I should make that image as profile image so I need that image dimension should resize and the image size should reduce, I need this to be done using PHP.. Any one provide me a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use this library. http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com. It's super easy to use for various operation with image.

Comment: In here, people help to find solution - not to do your job. Show your effort and look for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this function #http://codingzone.co

```
<?php 
    function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        return $destination;
    }

    $source_img = 'source.jpg';
    $destination_img = 'destination .jpg';

    $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many methods to do this , the following function will reduce the image size by adjusting it's quality.

```
    function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        return $destination;
    }

    $source_img = 'source.jpg';
    $destination_img = 'destination .jpg';
```

.

```
 $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

PHP function is used in the code that will pass the source image, destination image and quality for the image that takes to compress.

```
$info = getimagesize($source);
```

The getimagesize() function is also used to know the size of given image file and to return the dimensions including the file type.

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1280 [1] => 768 [2] => 2 [3] => width="1280" height="768" [bits] => 8 [channels] => 3 [mime] => image/jpeg )
```

```
imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
```

The imagejpeg() function is added in the code to make a JPEG file from the provided image.

Answer (score 0):

We can not reduce any file size while uploading.
Yes, We have option to compress but we can do that only for uploaded files only.... Cool...